# cygwin and BQ CLI not working... "-bash: bq: command not found"

Tags: google-bigquery, cygwin

I'm trying to script the loading of some data into GCP using the command line interface and I'm having an issue with cygwin with what i believe is a not complete install of BQ CLI.

From a DOS prompt I'm able to successfully run commands and load data so I believe I have it installed correctly on my desktop, Windows 10 64bit.

Is there some additional installation required to get cygwin to work correctly with BQ CLI that isn't installed by default with cygwin?

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem I was having... I was attempting to execute BQ from the cli using 'bq' and not 'bq.cmd'...

Working fine now...